# Ctrl + ` (backtick) shortcut is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 20.04

I use Ctrl + ` to toggle Guake / Tilda but after upgrade to 20.04 the shortcut doesn't work anymore (nothing happens when I press these keys).

I searched in keyboard shortcuts in system settings and didn't find a conflicting shortcut that used the same key combination.

Is it a bug or there is some hidden global shortcut?

Edit:

This is weird but after a few minutes after system startup Ctrl + ` starts working again...